# Where is invoicing information stored?

Tags: civievent, invoice

I enabled "Billing address required" on my event. Registering now shows fields to fill in.

But where do I look to retrieve it? It's not in the registration nor in the payment info, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the contact itself. It has become one of the addresses, the billing address.

Comment: So, if a contact wants to sign up to two paid events with different billing info, the last one will overwrite the first? And the first one will overwrite the one currently in the system?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Sounds uncommon to me. Would it be usual for the users of your site?

Comment: Not necessarily common, but might happen. Particluarly if you consider invoicing references, which usually is some "project id" or account. Enough of a risk for me to start thinking about it ;-)

Comment: you might add  custom fields, if needed even all fields you normally find in an address, to event registrations or to contributions.

Comment: Good point, I'll consider that.